# How rich was Croesus?

Tags: greek

My grandparents, who were fortunate to come from the generation when the classics were still at the core of education, often used the phrase "rich as Croesus".

But how rich was Croesus?

Comment: "By the fifth century at least, Croesus had become a figure of myth, who stood outside the conventional restraints of chronology." [J.A.S. Evans, "What Happened to Croesus?" The Classical Journal 74.1 (October 1978:34-40) examines the legend and the date 547 BC.]

Answer (score 2):

I looked for the same information many years ago and arrived at a website, that, at that time, stated that it could be estimated by the weight of the gold that he had accumulated. I remember that he was only one living at that period that had the greatest volume of gold, although Solomon, I believe it said, came close.

It also said that Croesus was by no means the richest person in history as far as gold goes, but the pharoahs from earlier times and such, would have owned more because, once, there was a lot more gold to easily extract under favorable circumstances.

Also, remember, that all of Croesus' wealth was captured by Cyrus when he took Lydia, just before Cyrus surprised and took Babylon.

It was years ago when I saw the webpage. In fact, it was at the beginning of the internet age. Like 1995 or so. It was a small and specialized website at the time and I suspect that it no longer exists, as it may have been updated into something better. By reading the Greek wikis and Turkish pages which cover the country where the nation of Lydia was located, it looks like you are able to gather plenty of information from the web.

Notice, that the entire kingdom of Lydia was absorbed by the new Persian Empire which, shortly, thereafter, went on to conquer the kingdom of Babylon. The Babylonian King was renowned for how much wealth they had accumulated, they having taken the treasures from the Assyrians and everyone they conquered thereafter.

There is a reason that the Persians became associated with the zenith of luxuries. Like, the rich Persian carpets, Persian Princess, etc. At some point they became more wealthy than even Croesus because they extended their holdings all the way into India which was supplying them with rare gemstones in addition to gold and precious metals.

Comment: *I arrived at a website* could you provide a link to the website?